# Trailing constraint on UIStackView not getting honored

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view with 4 buttons on it. I have applied leading and trailing constraints with regards to superview on it and I see leading constraint working, but not the trailing constraint.

I have everything in storyboard at this point and there are no constraints being added in code, so haven't pasted any code here. Just have the outlet in code to show the UI on the device.

Any idea why would this happen?

***Stack View in Storyboard***

[image: Stack View in Storyboard]

***Stack View on Device (see text going out of the device frame on right and no button border)***

[image]

***Stack View IB details:***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the debug UI yet? Or try to enable `Clip to Bounds` for your stack view.

Comment: @CanhTran - Clip to bounds didn't work. I looked using Debug UI and it shows me the same thing what I see on the device i.e. constraints or padding on the left side, but button gets cut off on the right. 

I even tried wrapping the stack view inside of a UIView where UIView leading and trailing aligns with superview and stack view leading and trailing is 15px from the UIView and even that didn't help. Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: have you added width to the buttons?

Comment: @Atmaram - I am letting stack view adjust the width of the buttons dynamically. Distribution property in stack view applies width to the buttons based on the value chosen for it.

Comment: if you have a custom class for the button then check the code for layout update on setting the content it could be forcing a new frame

Comment: @tech_human is the stackView embedded in another view then check constraints of that view.

Comment: Can you show us the full demo on public repo Github? Not sure if we're missing any information there.

Comment: your stack view setup doesn't work on smaller width device, also since u have mentioned  min spacing for stack view items as 15, there is no need to set leading and trailing among items inside stack view